# Java 8 extending function interface and combining them

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

I have a functional interface that extends standard jdk function to simply the generic types. Now I want to combine two functions using andThen which is throwing compiler error

> Error:(25, 25) java: method andThen in interface
>   `java.util.function.Function<T,R>` cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: `java.util.function.Function<? super
>   ui.instrumentation.api.messaging.Message<R>,? extends V>`   found:
>   `ui.instrumentation.api.transformation.Transformer<T,R>`   reason:
>   cannot infer type-variable(s) V
>       (argument mismatch; `ui.instrumentation.api.transformation.Transformer<T,R>` cannot be
>   converted to `java.util.function.Function<? super
>   ui.instrumentation.api.messaging.Message<R>,? extends V>`)

Here is the sample code:

```
public interface Transformer<T,R> extends Function<Message<T>, Message<R>> {

    static <T, R> Transformer<T, R> combine2(Transformer<T, R> first, Transformer<T, R> second) {
        return first.andThen(second));
    } 
}
```

Is there a way to combine functions that extends standard Function interface or is there better way to do this?

Comment: Why exactly do you need the `combine2` function, when `andThen` does literally the same thing, for the more general argument type `Function`?

Comment: So you want a function that takes a `Message<T>`, passes it to `first`, gets a `Message<R>` back, then somehow passes that `Message<R>` to `second` even though `second` needs a `Message<T>` not a `Message<R>`.

Comment: My recommendation: don’t use such extending interfaces. You save a few letters to type at the expense of not allowing to use existing implementations of the base interface (here `Function`). Thus, you need to re-implement everything, not only `andThen`, even trivial functions like `Function.identity()` can’t be used as `Transformer`. Learn the lesson from the other’s mistakes; despite having the same functional signature, you can’t use a `Transformer<T,T>`, where a `UnaryOperator<Message<T>>` is required (another example of not allowing the base type `Function`)…

Answer (score 5):

You need to both fix your generics, and instead of using `andThen`, which would only return a `Function`, you'll be better off inlining the lambda yourself:

```
static <T1, T2, T3> Transformer<T1, T3> combine2(Transformer<T1, T2> first, Transformer<T2, T3> second) {
    return (Message<T1> input) -> second.apply(first.apply(input));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The first problem is that `andThen` takes the return value of one function and makes that the parameter type of the next function, so you need, as @LouisWasserman explains, to chain them end-to-end with the output type of one matching the input type of the next:

```
static <T1, T2, T3> Transformer<T1, T3> combine2(Transformer<T1, T2> first, Transformer<T2, T3> second) {
```

The second problem, as he also explains, is that `Function.andThen`, which you are calling, returns a `Function`, not a `Transformer`. Note, however, that `Function` and `Transformer` have the same shape -- single input, single output.  Because of that, you can use one and then adapt it to the other with a method reference like this:

```
static <T1, T2, T3> Transformer<T1, T3> combine(Transformer<T1, T2> first, Transformer<T2, T3> second) {
    return first.andThen(second)::apply;
}
```

You don't need to create a function to do this.  You can use the same technique calling `Function.andThen()` directly:

```
    Transformer<String,Integer> t1 = ...
    Transformer<Integer,Double> t2 = ...
    Transformer<Double,String> t3 = ...

    Transformer<String,String> t123 = t1.andThen(t2).andThen(t3)::apply;
```

Comment: Thanks @HankD and @LouisWasserman, that helped me get better understanding. My original goal is to combine list of many functions (transformers in eg case) by chaining them with andThen. Look I really need to override combine method for each additional transformer like this
 
`static <T1, T2, T3, T4> Transformer<T1, T4> combine(Transformer<T1, T2> first, Transformer<T2, T3> second, Transformer<T3, T4> third) {
            return first.andThen(second).andThen(third)::apply;
        }`

Is there a better way to do this more generically combine list of functions?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you might do that